# How to sort ascending order by last modified date for s3 using aws cli

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-cli

Below code sort by desc. How do I have it sort by ascending?

```
KEY=`aws s3 ls $BUCKET --recursive | sort | tail -n 1 | awk '{print $4}'`
```

Answer (score 11):

It appears that you wish to **obtain the Key of the most recently modified object** in the Amazon S3 bucket.

For that, you can use:

```
aws s3api list-objects --bucket bucketname --query 'sort_by(Contents, &LastModified)[-1].Key' --output text
```

The AWS CLI `--query` parameter is highly capable. It uses [JMESPath](https://jmespath.org/), which can do most required manipulations without needing to pipe data.

The `aws s3api list-objects` command provides information in specific fields, rather than the `aws s3 ls` command which is simply text output.

The above *might not* work as expected if there are more than 1000 objects in the bucket, since results are returned in batches of 1000.

Answer (score -2):

Use:  sort -r for ascending order

From the manpage for sort

```
   -r, --reverse
          reverse the result of comparisons
```