# sorting an S3 bucket by last updated date

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-php-sdk

According to https://stackoverflow.com/a/65675842/569976 , you can use the AWS S3 CLI client to sort the results of a `list-objects-v2` by the last modified date, as follows:

```
aws s3api list-objects --bucket bucketname --query 'sort_by(Contents, &LastModified)[-1].Key' --output text
```

My question is...  how do you do that with the PHP client / `Aws\S3\S3Client::listObjects`?

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php/v3/api/api-s3-2006-03-01.html#listobjects mentions a bunch of options you can pass to it and none of them are "query":

```
$result = $client->listObjects([
    'Bucket' => '<string>', // REQUIRED
    'Delimiter' => '<string>',
    'EncodingType' => 'url',
    'ExpectedBucketOwner' => '<string>',
    'Marker' => '<string>',
    'MaxKeys' => <integer>,
    'OptionalObjectAttributes' => ['<string>', ...],
    'Prefix' => '<string>',
    'RequestPayer' => 'requester',
]);
```

Is it just not possible with the PHP API client?

Comment: The `query` is indeed not part of the API - it's done by the CLI itself.  If you need to do the same you'll need to sort the results locally.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`--query` is a [client-side parameter](https://github.com/aws/aws-cli/blob/bf0ca8139ca6f8f8ea0e4e13abadf5fda785d3a2/awscli/formatter.py#L257-L261) supported by AWS CLI. It's not a part of the API.

You'll need to sort the results in your PHP code.

This parameter uses [JMESPath](https://jmespath.org/) as a scripting language for modifying the output results. If you want to completely mimic its behavior, you can use a JMESPath library such as [this](https://github.com/jmespath/jmespath.php).

Answer (score 1):

As others have stated, `query` is not part of API parameters; instead you can use `JMESPath` which enables you to declaratively specify how to extract elements from a JSON document. The AWS SDK for PHP already has a dependency on [jmespath.php](https://github.com/jmespath/jmespath.php).

The `Aws\ResultInterface` interface has a `search($expression)` method that extracts data from a result model based on a JMESPath expression.

```
$expr = '<your_jmespath_expression>';
$data = $result->search($expr);
```